# Nagios Core 3.2.2 issue

Tags: nagios

I'm a total newbie to nagios, and I am getting the following error message via mail, is there anything I can do to resolve?

```
** PROBLEM Service Alert: localhost/Root Partition is CRITICAL **

***** Nagios *****

Notification Type: PROBLEM

Service: Root Partition
Host: localhost
Address: 127.0.0.1
State: CRITICAL

Date/Time: Fri Dec 21 09:24:00 GMT 2012

Additional Info:

DISK CRITICAL - free space: / 10467 MB (5% inode=99%):
```

Comment: Read through the notification again, carefully. Do you note anything that may *specifically* indicate an issue? It may also be helpful to visit the [Nagios documentation](http://www.nagios.org/documentation).

Comment: Thanks J, Should mention that 10GB of space on this server is lots, how do I set the alert to 5GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do either of two things:

- Change your nagios config to alert at a lower percentage free
- Fix the diskspace issue

I'd suggest doing the latter as disks operate much happier when there's some room available. As for do the former, for that we kinda need to see your nagios config as there are several ways of doing it (hardcoded in the command, parametrized and set per host, or maybe per hostgroup)...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the default configutation you will need to edit the following file

/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/localhost.cfg

Then look for

```
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        hostgroup                       linux-servers
        service_description             Root Partition
        check_command                   check_local_disk!20%!10%!/
        }
```

And change 20% to be the warning % free and 10% to the critical % then reload Nagios

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a low free inodes. Check this via

```
df -h
```

and

```
df -i
```

Comment: 99% of inodes free is not low